# How do I check the information sent by the GTM event trigger to Recommendations AI project?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-tag-manager

Could someone inform what is the most correct way to verify what is the information sent by the GTM event tag [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GOfM1.png) to an Recommendations AI project?

Comment: GTM does not really have a native "event" tag, so it is a little unclear what you are asking. But in general, what information is being sent is most easily checked by either using the network tab in your browser and inspect outgoing requests, or use a proxy such as Charles Proxy (not affiliated) to look at outgoing requests and see if the information is in there. But if you could expand a little on your question, there might be a proper answer.

Comment: I created a Cloud Retail tag in GTM (see screenshot in my question) with all necessary triggers. Now I need to verify if the triggers correctly activate the tag and what is the information sent by the tag to DataLayer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Confirm your triggers are not misfiring by using the preview mode in GTM: https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/6107056?hl=en
2. As Eike mentioned, open the Developer's console Network tab https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/network/
3. Clear the log in the Network tab. And select All in the Network filters.
4. Conduct an action that triggers your tag.
5. In the Network tab, there are now new activity is shown. Select the one that looks like your endpoint and that has a valid response code (it's almost always 200)
6. Scroll down to the Query String parameters and assess your payload:

Like so:
[image]